# Radio Button returning "undefined" value

Tags: javascript, ejs

I'm trying to write a program where the user clicks a radio button with a choice. When they press submit, it takes them to a page that changes based on the radio button clicked. I'm supposed to use node.js and an ejs template and the radio button keeps returning undefined. How do i get the radio button to return a value, then how do i get the page to display a unique text based on that value?

I've been working on this for several days and no solution seems to work.

```
        <input name="imagePick" value="2" type="radio" id="two" onclick="javascript:check();">
        <label for="two">
            <img src="images/taurus.png" alt="taurus" height="150" width="auto">
        </label>

        <input name="imagePick" value="3" type="radio" id="three">
        <label for="three">
            <img src="images/cancer.jpg" alt="gemini" height="150" width="auto">
        </label>
```

```
var sign = $('input[name="imagePick"]:checked').val();
console.log("the sign is: " + sign);

//I want the variable sign to be the value of the radio button clicked
```

Comment: Use `$("#checkbox").is(':checked')`. Checking the value of a non-text input would return undefined, since there is no value attribute.

Comment: It seems you are using jquery in your code. Is it correctly loaded in the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working fine. In the below snippet, the code is the same as yours, except I replaced your `onclick` by an `onchange` handler on both of the radio buttons.

Your initial code as is is also working (for the one radio button that has an `onclick` handler attached to it, that is).

So, as Adriano commented, it is possible that your jQuery libraries are not loaded correctly.

```js
$("input[name='imagePick']").on("change", function() {
  var sign = $('input[name="imagePick"]:checked').val();
  console.log("the sign is: " + sign);

  //I want the variable sign to be the value of the radio button clicked
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input name="imagePick" value="2" type="radio" id="two">
        <label for="two">
            <img src="images/taurus.png" alt="taurus" height="150" width="auto">
        </label>

        <input name="imagePick" value="3" type="radio" id="three">
        <label for="three">
            <img src="images/cancer.jpg" alt="gemini" height="150" width="auto">
        </label>
```